# Amazon UserData bootstrap script not able to restart pm2 process

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-data

I have an AutoScaling group on Amazon AWS.
It works perfectly apart from one thing. When userdata bootstrap script is executed it runs as root user and my pm2 process is running with ubuntu user.

Even if I switch user in the script it still says pm2 command not found

```
 //RESPONSE in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
 //Here is the response 
 Already up to date.
 ubuntu
 v8.10.0
 bash: npm: command not found
 From https://bitbucket.org/repo
  * branch              HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up to date.
 bash: pm2: command not found
```

Even node version in AMI is 10.15.1 but it prints 8.10.0

Here is my bootstrap script

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd /pathtodirectory
  git pull repo
  cd ..
  sudo touch yesiran
  cd folder
  su ubuntu bash -c "whoami"
  su ubuntu bash -c "git config --global core.mergeoptions --no-edit"
  su ubuntu bash -c "node -v"
  su ubuntu bash -c "npm -v"
  su ubuntu bash -c "pm2 reload all"
```

Comment: Is npm installed?

Comment: yes the AMI I created for the autoscaling group got everything up and running. 
currently, I have done pm2 startup and pm2 save in AMI to run the process on reboot.
The server from which I have shared logs successfully booted with the process running but not with the latest code